# What does this mean commit():Illegal for a non-transacted Session:sessionId

Tags: glassfish, jms

I am using a glassfish server and using the JMS functionality of that glassfish server.

Keep on getting this error message :

> MQJMSRA_DS4001: commit():Illegal for a non-transacted Session:sessionId

What is the reason I am getting this error message ?

Comment: it would help to give more details/excerpt on the code that is causing this, your connector config, your endpoints (queue/topic) config etc.

Comment: at a high-level it means you are trying to do a transaction-specific operation (such as commit/rollback), when you are not in a transaction. need more details to give a more specific answer.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you get that error is that your Session is not transacted . This means than commit/ rollback methods are meaningless. Try setting the session as transacted when you create it (E.g. connection.createSession(**true**, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE)). 
If you don't want your session to be transacted you should remove Commit / rollbacks from code, or cheching a global variable before executing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  **TransactionAwareConnectionFactoryProxy** .

Instead of using the raw vendor-provided ConnectionFactory, the configuration wraps ConnectionFactory in a decorator that handles the transaction synchronization. This happens in the jms-context.xml as follows :-

```
<bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.TransactionAwareConnectionFactoryProxy">
        <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="myCamelConnectionFactory"/>
</bean>

<jee:jndi-lookup id="myconnectionFactory" jndi-name="SoDConflictConnFactory"/>
```

This will remove the Warning message :-**MQJMSRA_DS4001**